# Defining operators for existing structure

Tags: c++, cuda

I am working with CUDA and C++. On the Linux server where I run my GPU programs some old compilers are installed. I am solving cumbersome differential equations with complex unknowns. In CUDA, there is a structure `double2` with members `x` and `y`, and operator `=` is determined, but there are no operators `+`,`*`, `-` etc.

Can I define those operators (both for complex-complex and complex-double arithmetics)? I know how to create my own class with operators, but I don't know how to modify operators for existing class (or structure).

Or it is worth to create my own class? So far I created it like this:

```
class CComplex{
public:
double x,y;
CComplex() {}
CComplex(double a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {}
};

CComplex operator+ (const CComplex&  lhs, const CComplex&  rhs){
CComplex temp;
temp.x = lhs.x + rhs.x;
temp.y = lhs.y + rhs.y;
return temp;
}

CComplex operator+ (const CComplex&  lhs, const double&  rhs){
CComplex temp;
temp.x = lhs.x + rhs;
temp.y = lhs.y;
return temp;
}

CComplex operator* (const CComplex&  lhs, const CComplex&  rhs){
CComplex temp;
temp.x = lhs.x * rhs.x-lhs.y*rhs.y;
temp.y = lhs.x*rhs.y+lhs.y*rhs.x;
return temp;
}

CComplex operator* (const CComplex&  lhs, const double&  rhs){
CComplex temp;
temp.x = lhs.x * rhs;
temp.y = lhs.y*rhs;
return temp;
}

CComplex operator- (const CComplex&  lhs, const CComplex&  rhs){
CComplex temp;
temp.x = lhs.x - rhs.x;
temp.y = lhs.y - rhs.y;
return temp;
}

CComplex operator- (const CComplex&  lhs, const double&  rhs){
CComplex temp;
temp.x = lhs.x - rhs;
temp.y = lhs.y;
return temp;
}
```

Not sure what is better and how fast CUDA is working with custom-created classes.

Comment: `thrust::complex` probably has much of what you need, and all of it can be used in ordinary CUDA C/C++ code.  You can also take a look in `cuComplex.h` (in `/usr/local/cuda/include`) for some definitions that may be useful.

Comment: A stand-alone function (not a method) `Double2 operator+ (const Double2& left, const Double2 &right);` should do the trick but I don't have time to test it now.  If someone want's to follow thru (and it works) feel free to take credit (grin).  Consider the techniques to define operator << for output streams and arbitrary types.  This is the same problem.

Comment: I would recommend using `thrust::complex`, but [here](http://pastebin.com/xxP94mES) is a worked example of extending the structs/definitions in `cuComplex.h` to add the `+` operator.

Comment: Since I don't need any Thurst reduction algorithms, I think it's not worth to use it

Comment: You don't have to use algorithms or any other part of thrust in order to make use of `thrust::complex` in your CUDA C/C++ code.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/dhMice4c) is my worked example from above reworked to use `thrust::complex`.

Comment: Thanks, your link doesn't open from my lab wi-fi. I'll take a look at home.